# ajax POST trouble passing variable

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am having issues passing a variable through aJax POST.  When I remove the 4th line of data (`old`) everything works perfectly.  I am trying to pass the value of the `<td>` being edited before it is edited along with after. Content is the value after the edit, so after the table `<td>` is selected but before it becomes editable content I grab the value of the cell.

This is what I am trying to pass through with the variable '`old`'.

```
        $('td').click(function(){

            var old=$(this).text();

            $(this).prop('contenteditable', true);

        });

        $('td').on('input',function() {
            console.log('event');    
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "updatedatabase.php",
                data: { 
                    content: $(this).text(), 
                    date: $(this).siblings().first().text(),
                    prod: $('tr:first-child th:nth-child(' + ($(this).index() + 1) + ')').text(),
                    old
                }
            })
                .done(function( msg ) {
                alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
            });

        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass three types to data **Type: PlainObject or String or Array** (as mentioned in **[jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)** documentation) and since you're passing an object you can't just put a variable `old` inside an object, you should pass name and value like `name: value,name: value,...`, so it should be like `old: old` :

```
var old=""; //--->Define variable

$('td').click(function(){
    old=$(this).text(); //--->Set variable
    $(this).prop('contenteditable', true);
});

$('td').on('input',function() {
    ...

    data: { 
        content: $(this).text(), 
        date: $(this).siblings().first().text(),
        prod: $('tr:first-child th:nth-child(' + ($(this).index() + 1) + ')').text(),
        old: old //--->Get variable
    }

    ...
});
```

Take a look to **[Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)** documentation.

**NOTE :** You have to declare you variable `old` globaly so it will defined inside the both events `click` and `input`.

Hope this helps.

---

```js
var old="";
var show_notification = false;

$('td').click(function(){
  show_notification = true;
  old=$(this).text();

  $(this).prop('contenteditable', true);
});

$('td').on('input',function() {
  if(show_notification===true){
    toastr.info(old,'Old text',{"timeOut": 2000});
    show_notification = false;
  }


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/1.3.1/css/toastr.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/1.3.1/js/toastr.js"></script>

<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>first td</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>second</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>third</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I have tried old:old but there is still an issue.  The reason I can tell there is an issue is because when I take old out completely I get the message response from .done .   When I have old in there or old:old I never get the message so for some reason ajax is not able to complete.

Comment: _so for some reason ajax is not able to complete_ That right, because it can't find the variable `old` i've just noticed that your variable is not declared as global check my update.

Comment: You're welcome, i've added a snippet so you could see the `old` value shows when you edit the `td`'s.

Comment: That is actually a very good idea.  See I am building this to take the place of a spreadsheet that the production supervisor used to put his schedule together.  It would actually be pretty cool if it was possible to have a window pop up saying the old value so that when he goes to edit, he knows what the old value was if he wants to go back.  I wouldnt want anything you have to click or exit out of though because thatd be extra work.  Something that would go away on its own after maybe 5 seconds would be great, so you could ignore and just keep working if you wanted.  Any ideas?

Comment: possibly something that looks something like this: https://gyazo.com/936a57892f0b557dfbfbe97babee4b63  I dont know if thats possible or not.  Like I said I wouldnt want the production manager to need to click out, it would just go away on his own so the he doesnt have to click "ok" after every single edit, but the info is then there if he wants to see it.

Comment: Yes i've a suggestion, using `toastr` plugin.. check my update, take a look to http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html

Comment: That is awesome!!!  Looks like it will work great for what I want!  Ive never used a plugin before so I will have to figure out how to install

Comment: No installation needed, just import `toastr.js` and `toastr.css` as i do in the snippet `<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/1.3.1/css/toastr.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/1.3.1/js/toastr.js"></script>`.

Comment: Playing with toastr, I used : 
'toastr.info(old,'Your Previous Amount Was:',{"timeOut": 2000, "positionClass": "toast-top-center"}); ' but its giving me center left instead?  I just copy and pasted from what you had in the sniplet and then added possition class in to it.

Comment: Yes i see, not sure why but you could use it like .. http://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/vCBev/29/

Comment: very strange, works perfect in JSfiddle, but behaves differently on my site.  See these 2 screenshots, literally cut and pasted code...

https://gyazo.com/a5e1c650869e66abe3b62feaa81a922d
https://gyazo.com/156bb7c0b2afa2f8354103d9387e7336

Answer (score 1):

Your variable "old" is scoped within the td click handler. It's not visible to the other function because it doesn't exist outside that click handler. The simplest - but very out of fashion - solution is to declare var old in the global scope (ie. just say var old; at the top of your script) and only assign it in the click handler. You can then use a closure to shield the variable. I will include an example below. Other possible solutions include assigning old to an attribute within the TD or using localStorage/sessionStorage.

```
(function(){
      var old;
      $('td').click(function(){
        old=$(this).text();
        $(this).prop('contenteditable', true);
      });  

      $('td').on('input',function() {
         console.log('event');    
         $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "updatedatabase.php",
            data: { 
              content: $(this).text(), 
              date: $(this).siblings().first().text(),
              prod: $('tr:first-child th:nth-child(' + ($(this).index() + 1) + ')').text(),
              old: old
            }
         })
         .done(function( msg ) {
             alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
         });
       });
    })();
```

Comment: Ahh!!  I see what you mean about it being lost in the function.  declaring it at the top of the script now fixes my code from breaking but the value being placed in the click function is still hidden and lost forever.  I am still very new to programming but cant I put old inside of the function quotes or something like that to bring it back out of the function?

Comment: Make sure that the variable "old" inside the function does not have the "var" keyword in front of it. If it does, then you create a *new* variable named old within this narrower scope. You want to use the same global one for everything.